# Building a catch-all function for rendering

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am currently trying to render a calendar that uses checkboxes as filtering. I have all the filters working if I do it this way:

```
//Call my render event on click of a checkbox
$('.filterable-content__criteria').on('change', function(){
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('rerenderEvents');
});
```

This works so everytime I click a checkbox, it re-renders my calendar - thus showing/hiding events. Right now I am doing this relatively staticly where in my render function I do this:

```
var eventAcceptedClasses = [];
if ($('input#Event-Type-2').is(':checked')){
    eventAcceptedClasses.push(id);
    displayEvent = false;
} else if ($('input#Event-Type-2').is(':checked')){
    eventAcceptedClasses.push('Event-Type-2');
    displayEvent = false;
} else if ($('input#Event-Type-3').is(':checked')){
    eventAcceptedClasses.push('Event-Type-3');
    displayEvent = false;
}  else {
    //If none checked, show all.
    eventAcceptedClasses.push('fc-event');
    displayEvent = true;
};
```

This function is regrettably, not scalable. I'm looking to make it so on render, it takes the id of the checkbox that was clicked, then plugs it into the function ie: You set the id in the click event like this

```
var cb_click = event.target.id
```

Then my render just looks like this:

```
var eventAcceptedClasses = [];
if ($('input#'+cb_click ).is(':checked')){
    eventAcceptedClasses.push(cb_click);
    displayEvent = false;
}
```

But given the way the functions are nested, this doesn't seem to work due to the structure of the code.

Any ideas on how I can do this? I included a **[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lcup8fev/)** that shows the full structure for clarification.

Edit:

**Basic Input Structure**

```
<input class="filterable-content__criteria" type="checkbox" name="categories" value="Event Type 1" id="Event-Type-1">
```

Comment: Please clarify your question and show us the html!

Comment: Can't you just put all the control ids and events into a data structure that you loop over?

Comment: @Cryptopat HTML has very little to with this, as it's only a single input with an id. This is the general structure of the inputs, give or take the value and id changing. `<input class="filterable-content__criteria" type="checkbox" name="categories" value="Event Type 1" id="Event-Type-1">`

Comment: @reggaeguitar I'm trying to do this fully dynamically where it just grabs the id from the clicked elements, as opposed to building the 'wordbank' of ids in the JS

Comment: To grab the id of element on click, just call a function into the onclick attribute. `onclick="myfunction(this.id)"` The myFunction() must have a var declared `myFunction(whatever){whatever.style..}` The whatever part is then the element id into the function

Comment: I'm able to get the id with `event.target.id` but I can't seem to pass it into my render function @Cryptopat

Comment: Yep just wrap it into a top level function, and pass the id into the function just like shown? So you would be able to use `whatever` aka the clicked element id, anywhere in your function.

Comment: @Cryptopat Trying that now, but it keeps returning this for the id now, as opposed to the id of the input `function (a,b){return new e.fn.init(a,b,h)}`

Comment: Note that you do not need to preface an id selector with an element name; in other words, `$("#" + cb_click)` will actually be a bit faster, since ids must be unique to the document.

Answer (score -1):

If you can modify the html, adding an `onchange` attribute to your input is the way to go.

It is much simpler to understand, and is better for memory usage than an *event listener*, or a redundant testing `if else`.

In a short example, with just javascript, to call a function that pass the id of the current clicked element.

```js
//Call my render event on click of a checkbox

function call_render(me){

    console.log(me)
    /* eventType1 */
    
    // me.fullCalendar('rerenderEvents');
}
```

```html
Tick: <input onchange="call_render(this.id)" id="eventType1" class="filterable-content__criteria" type="checkbox" name="categories" value="Event Type 1">
```

Sometimes we just can't modify the html from the source.

The html can also become a bit unreadable when too much attributes are set.

It is also not so good for fixing stuffs and readability when javascript is written inside html attribute, like in the previous example.

Attributes needs to be set at the DOM level. It is better practice. There is alternatives, but it's always better to use html capabilities first.

```js
// DOM now ready

// Set the onchange attribute to the element *eventType1*.
// And give this attribute a function when a change happen

eventType1.setAttribute("onchange","call_render(this.id)")

//Call my render event on click of a checkbox

function call_render(me){

    console.log(me)
    /* eventType1 */
    
    // me.fullCalendar('rerenderEvents');
}
```

```html
Tick: <input class="filterable-content__criteria" type="checkbox" name="categories" value="Event Type 1" id="eventType1">
```

To verify or test the checkbox state:

```js
console.log( (eventType1.checked) )

console.log( !(eventType1.checked) )
```

```html
Tick: <input id="eventType1" type="checkbox" checked="">
```

Again, we can also set a global event handler like this:

```
eventType1.oninput = (function() {
     call_render(this.id)

  })
```

Js perf test, to compare the 3 methods.
I removed the querySelector, the inline onchange is stil faster. 
https://jsperf.com/global-vs-event-vs-inline

[image]

Comment: Better provide evidence if you're going to make a claim like "inline event handlers use less memory". Of course, the point of using `addEventListener` is to keep your presentation separate from your behavior.

Comment: I had provide a solution on the second example regarding the presentation aspect. It is a one time set.

Comment: You are downvoting yourself bro

Comment: You stated "...is better for memory usage than an event listener..." What evidence do you have of this? Setting an attribute is silly when you can just use `$('.filterable-content__criteria').on('change', function(){...` _as the author already has_. I read your answer and found it to be ridiculous and full of "better practice" claims not backed up by references.

Comment: . Setting an attribute, is a global event handler, not an event listener. It can be set like this too `onchange = (function(){})()` the behavior is the same. `on('change'` is an event listener, it stay always active. Make sure to leave  jquery and event listener , they are both outdated.

Comment: So... you have no evidence for your claims. Just making sure.

Comment: I am not going to write a testing suite, no. Not tonight. Maybe tomorrow!

Comment: A simple pure js show the onchange method much fast on firefox: https://jsperf.com/globalevent-vs-enventlistener/ feel free to add the jquery test case.

Comment: But faster was not the claim you made. You said "is better for memory usage", which the perf test does not measure.